# Spoon: No more handles [Could not detect registered XULRunner to use]

Tags: pentaho, kettle, xulrunner, spoon

I am using Pentaho Data Integration tool 4.4.0 on my Ubuntu 14.04

```
uname -a
Linux LT0124 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:30:00 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When I am closing PDI I am getting pop up window with following error:

```
An unexpected error occurred in Spoon:
No more handles [Could not detect registered XULRunner to use]
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: [Could not detect registered XULRunner to use]
...

![Spoon pop up window with an error][1]
```

I am using following version of java:

```
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

Please do let me know how can I get rid of this error.

Answer (score 1):

I am running PDI 5, and I found that adding  `-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla` to OPT in spoon.sh fixed my PDI from not starting at all.

Give it a try.

Comment: Hi, I have it already in the OPT. This doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Matt Casters just tipped us to update swt.jar: If you're having Spoon problems on Linux/OSX after an upgrade, try upgrading swt.jar from http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.3.2-201402211700/ …